# Visual C++ - folder structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have started to learn C++ and i stuck in front of MSVC.
Have you any idea about why MSVC have this folder structure?
What is the purpose 'x64' folder inside 'Hostx86'?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B233X.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hostx86/x64 means the toolset (compiler, linker, etc) that is running on x86 32-bit host (that is 32-bit x86 applications), but produces x64 binaries.